# How to solve "This type of page is not served" error in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my asp.net file i linked only one page in .asp file.When click this page it show some error[image]

How to solve this error?

Comment: Should probably be .aspx, not .asp

Comment: That isn't asp.net, asp is the old MS webpage tech.  This has absolutely nothing to do with C# or ASP.NET, it has to do with a silly error (did you mean .aspx?) or configuring asp.net to serve asp pages (off topic here).

Comment: It's an asp.net error message, so asp.net thinks it's responsible for dealing with that site.

Answer (score 1):

If this is not a typo, like mantioned in comments, so you *really* want to serve to the client a page with `ASP` extension, you have to change, add to be more precise, an extension with clearly defined `mime type` to the `IIS` configuration file.

Comment: +1 for `typo, like mantioned in comments`